# Amcharts Horizontal Bar Chart Label Issue

Tags: data-visualization, visualization, amcharts, amcharts4

the load bullet text is getting trimmed automatically. We tried multiple options but it doesn’t seem to work. Please advise.

var labelBullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet())

labelBullet.label.horizontalCenter = "left";

labelBullet.label.dx = 10;

labelBullet.label.text = "{valueDisplay}";

[image]

labelBullet.locationX = 0;

labelBullet.minWidth = 20; -- tried this

labelBullet.width = 200; -- and this as well

If we choose location = 1, then also it is getting cut

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can simply say:

```
labelBullet.label.truncate = false;
labelBullet.label.hideOversized = false;
```

More info [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/using-label-bullets-on-a-horizontal-bar-chart/#Controlling_label_truncation)!

Comment: It didn't help :(